# Recurring BSOD problems while running a Minecraft Server (Java)

Tags: windows-7, bsod, hardware-failure

I'm wondering if anyone can help me read into the two recent BSODs that occurred while running a Minecraft Server. I have been hosting a server for my friends and I on and off for a couple months at a time, for years. This has never been a problem in the past.

Here is a .zip of the two dumps associated with the BSODs.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByAB8Dluj_yLUEpPcThNZkM2dGM

I saw "FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x124_AuthenticAMD_PROCESSOR_CACHE" in there which would lead me to believe it is hardware, but I have no prior experience analyzing these dump files and help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Run memory tests on all your RAM and consider opening the case, etc. and unseating and reseating the memory first. While you are at it, blow all dust out of the enclosure of the machine while you reseat the RAM chips, and give it a visual inspection, etc. too. Consider running `SFC /SCANNOW` as well and ensuring all Windows Updates are installed and device drivers are up to date. One change at a time and be sure to have backups obviously if this system and/or the data is critical.

Comment: any update? is the issue fixed via BIOS update?

Answer (score 1):

[Analyzing the dump with windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) shows that you have a L1 Cache issue when writing data `DCACHEL1_DWR_ERR`:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, Machine Check Exception
Arg2: fffffa800d1cc028, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
Arg3: 00000000f6602000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.
Arg4: 0000000000000145, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

Debugging Details:
------------------

3: kd> !errrec fffffa800d1cc028
===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ fffffa800d1cc028
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01d3494b99e06845
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 10/20/2017 4:19:02 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa800d1cc0a8
Section       @ fffffa800d1cc180
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x64
Error Type    : Cache error
Operation     : Data Write
Flags         : 0x00
Level         : 1
CPU Version   : 0x0000000000100fa0
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000003

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa800d1cc0f0
Section       @ fffffa800d1cc240
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000003
CPU Id        : a0 0f 10 00 00 08 06 03 - 09 20 80 00 ff fb 8b 17
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ fffffa800d1cc240

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa800d1cc138
Section       @ fffffa800d1cc2c0
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : DCACHEL1_DWR_ERR (Proc 3 Bank 0)
  Status      : 0xf660200000000145
  Address     : 0x000000028939fe00
  Misc.       : 0x0000000000000000

3: kd> !sysinfo machineid
BiosVersion = 2101   
BiosReleaseDate = 04/08/2011
BaseBoardProduct = M4A89GTD-PRO/USB3
BaseBoardVersion = Rev 1.xx
```

[Update to BIOS 3030](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M4A89GTD_PROUSB3/HelpDesk_BIOS/) and look if this helps. Also try to increase the Voltage of the CPU a bit. If nothing helps, the AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1090T is damaged and needs to be replaced.